# Smallest and largest value of a function defined by an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x)$ is defined for $x \geq 0$ as

$$f(x) = \int_0^{x^2-x} \frac{1}{1 + t^6}dt$$

a. Decide if $f$ has a smallest value and if that is the case decide for which $x$.

b. Decide if $f$ has a largest value and if that is the case decide for which $x$.

Solution:

a. Because the integrand is positive $f$ is minimal when the upper bound is minimal. Because $x^2 - x = (x - 1/2)^2 - 1/4$ is minimal when $x=1/2$ then the integral is minimal at this $x$ too. Hence $f$ has a minimal value when $x=1/2$

b. I have no idea how to approach part b. Can anyone give a hint what to do?

Comment: b. The integrand is always positive, so $f(x)$ is always strictly increasing for $x>\frac{1}{2}$, so it has no largest value.

Comment: Oh yes, didnt think of that.